# Auto hot key mapping to switch Control and Alt ^<+Tab::ShiftAltTab does not work

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to use the following Auto Hot Key shortcuts to switch CTRL and ALT:

```
LCtrl & Tab::AltTab
return 

^<+Tab::ShiftAltTab
return
```

But I've got an error `The AltTab hotkey "^<+Tab" must specify which key (L or R).`

Changed then I get another error: `... must have exactly one modifier/prefix.`

```
<^<+Tab::ShiftAltTab
return
```

I found my question asked on Reddit too but no answer there:
https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/bb5xlv/tab_for_alttab_tab_for_shiftalttab_how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
; LCtrl + Tab
<^Tab::
    Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
    KeyWait, LCtrl ; waits for LCtrl to be relesead
    Send, {Alt Up}
return

; LCtrl + LShift + Tab
<^<+Tab::
    Send, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Tab}
    KeyWait, LCtrl
    KeyWait, LShift
    Send, {Alt Up}
return
```